# Hide property from IntelliSense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

How do I hide the `Base64EncodedCertificate` property from viewing in IntelliSense?

I tried those following attribute options and they don't work.

```
public class ThirdParty
{
    private string _Base64EncodedCertificate = null;

    public Guid ThirdPartyId { get; set; }
    // Notice: Allowed in source code use but not allowed in EFCore (EFCore doesn't support this).
    [NotMapped]
    public X509Certificate2 Certificate
    {
        get { return (_Base64EncodedCertificate == null ? null : new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(_Base64EncodedCertificate))); }
        set { _Base64EncodedCertificate = (value == null ? null : Convert.ToBase64String(value.GetRawCertData())); }
    }
    // Notice: Not allowed in Source code but is used by EFCore (EFCore limitation workaround).
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Bindable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string Base64EncodedCertificate
    {
        get { return _Base64EncodedCertificate; }
        private set { }
    }
    public string RawData { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A quick test shows that it is hidden when referenced from another solution. If it is the same solution then Visual Studio (I did not check Code) does not respect these settings. I would guess that this is intentional because the feature is for preventing *other developers* from seeing advanced members, not for preventing the current developer from working with these members.

Comment: possibly a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58049533/11107541. not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mark the question as ef related, but from the comment on the property in the source code -

```
// Notice:Not allowed in Source code but is used by EFCore (EFCore limitation workaround).
```

if i get it right, you're using it only for queries / insert / update, and if this is the case you can hide the member using [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) or [backing fields without public properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field#fields-without-a-property)

Comment: Oh wow!  I didn't know `Backing Fields` can be done.  That's new to me.  At least I can have more cleaner code on this one.  Whew!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have ReSharper installed? Then try to look this option:

[image: ReSharper InteliSense]