# Delete a specific Intellisense suggestion in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Intellisense sometimes comes up with irrelevant suggestions that I will never use in my project. Those can get in the way of the valuable other suggestions.

They also prevent VS Code features like "Add all missing imports" from working.

For example:

[image]

The first DocumentType is a low-level module that I will never use.
The second is one that I need in most of my files.

**So how can I get rid of the first one?**

Comment: The 2nd link isn't really related because it's for Visual Studio, which is a completely different IDE than Visual Studio Code (despite the name).

Comment: Maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916941/find-and-disable-filter-dom-intellisense-recommendations-in-vs-code/57917499#57917499 if you are using javascript or typescript (tsconfig then).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot disable specific IntelliSense completion options, however, there are a few other relevant caveats.

Answer to not your question: You can filter whole classes of keywords with the editor setting `editor.suggest.filteredTypes`. See more about this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45039#issuecomment-470614312).

IntelliSense does not allow you to configure or filter specific keywords. The list of all IntelliSense options is [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense). It also appears this is impossible with other major options. For example, the language server protocol does not support this([GitHub thread abt this](https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol/issues/898)). That being said, there is a plethora of autocomplete extensions and I'm certain this feature exists for some.

Something like [intellicode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode) might also be an answer, as it will look through other files you've edited to try to learn your practices.

If you're 100% sold on IntelliSense, and you're willing to sink several hours into this, you *could* set up a discrete language server, and then use something like [this](https://github.com/jacobdufault/lsp-filter) to filter completions as they are sent to the editor. While this would work, I think it's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

After spending several hours with no satisfying result, I created my own IntelliSense snippets. I used another keyword to make sure, it will show on top.

I used the [Easy Snippet plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=inu1255.easy-snippet) for this.