# Is there a way to disable a specific suggestion in VSCode intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, styled-components

I've been learning React recently, having styled-components installed in my project. Got a pretty helpful extension for css intellisense inside backticks, "vscode-styled-components", but one suggestion is incredibly annoying for me.

When you type 'var', then open parentheses, it autocompletes to 'var()()' with the cursor being inside the second one. I am used to opening parentheses by hand, and even if you don't and hit enter, it autocompletes to 'var()' with the cursor after ')', which is still somewhat counter-intuitive.

Is there a way to disable a specific suggestion, with 'settings.json' for example? This might be handy with other suggestions too in the future. Thanks.

Comment: It is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049533/delete-a-specific-intellisense-suggestion-in-vs-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a specific Intellisense suggestion in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049533/delete-a-specific-intellisense-suggestion-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:
[Delete a specific Intellisense suggestion in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049533/delete-a-specific-intellisense-suggestion-in-vs-code)

Here is the git hub thread it references if you would like to go straight to that:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45039#issuecomment-470614312

Comment: Saw the old thread after posting my question, but it still left the specific disabling unsolved, hoped it changed, huh. Still useful tho, thanks.