# How to get rid of typescript intellisense

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

how do I disable these typescript intellisense suggestions?

[image]

I am using JavaScript in a React project which comes with typescript as a dev dependency (Create React App). If I select an option from the screenshot labeled as coming from typescript it will import from 'typescript'. I want to disable suggestions coming from typescript but **not** a particular set of suggestions (ex: snippets, classes, etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a specific Intellisense suggestion in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049533/delete-a-specific-intellisense-suggestion-in-vs-code)

Comment: That is about deleting specific keywords from suggestions, I want to disable every suggestion that's coming from typescript.