# VSCode: Turn off specific autocomplete items

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type `span.h-10`, after typing `.`, I get `StereoPannerNode.` which really sucks. But other times I want to have this setting enabled. Can I disable **specific** settings?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a specific Intellisense suggestion in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049533/delete-a-specific-intellisense-suggestion-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable specific IntelliSense completion options. You can only filter or disable according to classes.
In addition to that [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense) you have the all things which can customized on visual studio code IntelliSense.

Comment: Answered my question, explained, and provided a link with more info, all in a concise paragraph. Thanks